# trying to login to agora rtm but receive the following error: The vendor enabled the dynamic key, but uses the static key

Tags: agora.io

Hey guys i'm trying to log into agora rtm using javascript and passed the following params to the login function:

param 1: `token = null;`
param 2: `uid = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000))`

passed them to the login function as follows:

```
await client.login({token, uid});
```

however recieve the following error messages:

**RTM:ERROR  Error Code 5 - The vendor enabled the dynamic key, but uses the static key. RTM:ERROR Error Code 5: login failed with args: {"token":null,"uid":"91**"}.**

does anyone have a workaround for this? i have set the project as 'testing' in the agora console

Answer (score 0):

The vendor(appId) you are using has token enabled or you can say need a token and appId
for authentication.